# Unexpected Token Illegal with onclick Java Script in Salesforce.com

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this most of the morning but to no end.  I am trying to execute a button that uses OnClick Java in Salesforce.com and it keeps throwing errors.  I think the issue may be with special characters in the data as it works when I simply use just text.  But any time numbers or any special characters are present I get the error "unexpected token ILLEGAL".  Can anyone help me to see what I am doing wrong and how I can get away from failing when special characters are involved?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 


var opptyObj = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
var today = new Date();
var sOpptyId = "{!Case.Opportunity__c}";

if( sOpptyId != "")
{ 
alert("This case is already tied to an opportunity!");
} 
else
{ 
opptyObj.AccountId = "{!Case.AccountId}";
opptyObj.CloseDate = sforce.internal.dateTimeToString(today);
opptyObj.Description="{!Case.Description}";
opptyObj.Case__c = "{!Case.Id}";
opptyObj.Name = "{!Case.Subject}";
opptyObj.StageName = "Estimate in Progress";
opptyObj.Created_from_Case__c = "Y";
opptyObj.Type = "New Business";
opptyObj.Amount = ".01";

var opptyresult = sforce.connection.create([opptyObj]);

if (opptyresult[0].success=='false') 
{ 
alert("Opportunity creation failed: " + opptyresult[0].errors.message);
} 
else 
{ 
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
caseObj.Opportunity__c = opptyresult[0].id;
caseObj.Status = "Estimate in Progress";

var caseResult = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);

if(caseResult[0].success == 'false') 
{ 
alert("Case update failed: " + caseResult[0].errors.message);
} 
else 
{ 
alert("An opportunity has been created and linked to this case.");
location.reload(true);
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: To make this even stranger, with certain text in the Description box on the case it works, but whenever there is more than one URL mentioned an error is fired.

Comment: Is this JavaScript being pre-processed by something via those `{!Foo.Bar}` tags? If so, that is inserting stuff that breaks JavaScript syntax rules.

Comment: Ah!  I seem to have found where the error is coming into play.  anytime that there is a Return inside of the Description box I am getting the error "unexpected token Illegal".  Is there anyway to work around returns in this type of format?

Comment: @AlexWayne this is being used inside of salesforce.com so the {!.} is used as a call on a particular field on an object.  The object is defined before the  . and the field is defined at the end.  So an account field called Account name would look like {!Account.Name}.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is some kind of template, whatever is rendering this needs to properly escape some values in the strings it's inserting.

Given this:

```
opptyObj.Description="{!Case.Description}";
```

Let's say I enter a description consisting of this:

> "That is awesome," said John.

When that is rendered in your template the result is this:

```
opptyObj.Description=""That is awesome," said John.";
```

As you might be able to see, the result is a syntax error.

You need to escape quote characters in an text inserted this way.  And without knowing what is technology rendering this template I can't give you any specifics, but you want to replace `"` with `\"` and `'` with `\'`. The `\` escapes characters, forcing them to be treated as literal characters in the string instead of other special meaning.

This must be done as it's being inserted into the script. Something in the spirit of this:

```
opptyObj.Description="{!Case.Description.replace(/'/, "\\'").replace(/"/, '\\"')}
```

Exactly how to do that depends on what language or template engine is being used here.  But th eresult should look like this:

```
opptyObj.Description="\"That is awesome,\" said John.";
```

---

Ruby on Rails [implements an `escape_javascript` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript), which sanitizes data for injection into Javascript.  It does the following replacements. It seems like a good baseline.

- `'\\'` => `'\\\\'`
- `'</'` => `'<\/'`
- `"\r\n"` => `'\n'`
- `"\n"` => `'\n'`
- `"\r"` => `'\n'`
- `'"'` => `'\\"'`
- `"'"` => `"\\'"`

---

UPDATE:

According to this: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_security_tips_scontrols.htm

It looks like you want the `JSENCODE` function.  Something like this, perhaps?

```
opptyObj.Description="{!JSENCODE(Case.Description)}";
```

Comment: Interesting, within my formula editor in salesforce.com it takes the syntax but the error remains when executing with Chrome.  I have run several test to see what the error could be but it seems the data in the field is what is causing the error.  The data contains URL's and several spaces as it is an email string pasted into the Description.  Could this cause errors like what I am experiencing? and if so would your method still allow that data to pass to my other object?

Comment: Basically, this button is taking data from a Case object in Salesforce and placing the data into the Opportunity object and then tieing the two together.

Comment: When troubleshooting any templating engine's output, and this _is_ a templating engine, you have to look at the output.  So when the description one one that messes everything up, what is literal output? (Disclaimer: I know nothing about sales force, but the problem seems clear, I just don't know what tools sales force gives you to fix it.)

Comment: No worries. I know little of Java so we will be the blind leading the blind on this one.  basically I have an input field in saleforce.com called description, and everytime that this field has data in it that has a break in the text string I get the error "unexpected token illegal" I suspect that this is because of the line breaks.  And if that is the case then I have no idea how to handle that.

Comment: salesforce doesnt really give you much to fix it :)

Comment: Java _Script_! **Java** is a completely different thing. This difference is critical to understand.

Comment: it takes the syntax, it just doesnt execute when line breaks are in the data

Comment: That's because javascript string literals are not allowed to have line breaks. You must use the escaped new line character `\n` instead. In the conversion chart I pasted above this is covered by `"\n" => '\n'`. It finds new lines in the string, and replaces it with an escaped version.  You want to end up with `"line1\nline2"`.

Comment: See my update, which I found via googling for "sales force escape javascript"

Comment: FANTASTIC!  Initial testing is fruitful!

Comment: I had previously tried this same function but it looks like I had something out of place,the                        opptyObj.Description="{!JSENCODE(Case.Description)}";  seems to work correctly